# Convert SQL request to Hibernate Criteria

Tags: sql, hibernate, criteria

I would like to convert this SQL into either Criteria. I am sorry I don't know which one to use since I'm new to Hibernate. I've done some research, and it looks like both are needed to achieve what I wanted.

My Sql Request

```
 select * 
from change.pade pade, change.pade_etat rdp, par.safsit safsit, par.saf saf
where pade.sir = "1245454"
and pade.id_safsit = "1"
and pade.id_safsit = safsit.id
and safsit.cd_s in ("12", "45")
and safsit.fk_saf = saf.id
and saf.cd_ur in "124"
and rdp.fk_pade = pade.id
and rdp.id_etat in "444"
```

Comment: Try to google, lot's of tutorials are there. Well you can solve it using any one of these `HQL,Native SQL in hibernate,Criteria Query`. If you need here is a [Criteria Query Example] (http://www.javamakeuse.com/2015/07/tutorial-hibernate-criteria-query.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Hibernate properties instead of writing `HQL` like this

```
session.createSQLQuery(String sqlQuery)
```

[see an example here](http://www.roseindia.net/hibernate/hibernate-native-sql.shtml)